# Read port data COMM (SerialEventListener) - Java

Tags: java

all right? I'm trying to convert C # code to Java and I'm having some problems…

I'm trying to read a serial port,

```
Global
private InputStream inputStream;
private OutputStream outputStream;
```

---

```
outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
```

To send the data, is going right, the problem is time to read it.

In C#, I have a receive method:

```
public void recepcaoResposta(int tam, byte[] frameHex)
{
    byte[] l_frameHex = new byte[2000];
    byte[] frameEvt = new byte[16];
    string linha, linhaTipo;

    // !! Copia vetor-parâmetro para vetor-local (evita exception nos "if's"
    //caso apenas 1 byte recebido) !!
    Buffer.BlockCopy(frameHex, 0, l_frameHex, 0, tam);
    .....
}
```

Converting to Java looks like:

```
public void recepcaoResposta(int tam, byte[] frameHex) {
    byte[] l_frameHex = new byte[2000];
    byte[] frameEvt = new byte[16];
    String linha, linhaTipo;

    // !! Copia vetor-parâmetro para vetor-local (evita exception nos "if's"
    //caso apenas 1 byte recebido) !!
    System.arraycopy(frameHex, 0, l_frameHex, 0, tam);
    ...
}
```

So far ok, the problem is time to get the tam, which is the size of the array. In java I have the return of size 8, whatever I do, comes the 8.

I even tried to change the ifs that have a "random" number size to 8. BUT obviously I got errors...

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
//                    int t = inputStream.read();
                int t = serialPort.getDataBits();
                byte[] f = new byte[t];
                inputStream.read(f, 0, t);  // Frame de bytes
                recepcaoResposta(t, f);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception in SerialEvent()" + e);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

But as said, I only have the return of size 8, which in this code above is:

```
int t = serialPort.getDataBits();
```

The result is basically like this:

```
TAM:8
l_frameHex[1]12
TAM:8
l_frameHex[1]23
```

Comment: `getDataBits()` returns the number of **bits** (not bytes) *configured* for the serial port, and the value can be 5, 6, 7 or 8. It has no relation to the number of bytes that you can currently read from the InputStream. Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/SerialPort.html#getDataBits()

Comment: Yes, watching a little while before I realized.

`// byte [] readBuffer = new byte [2000];
// int t = inputStream.read (readBuffer);
   int t = inputStream.available ();`

I tested it like that, but it keeps returning me random and wrong values.

`run:
1
8
1
4
4
1
3
5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of trying I got it, it's working perfectly:

```
public static InputStream inputStream;
public static OutputStream outputStream;

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
    switch (evt.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI:
        //Quebra interupção.
        case SerialPortEvent.OE:
        //Erro de saturação.
        case SerialPortEvent.FE:
        //Erro de enquadramento.
        case SerialPortEvent.PE:
        //Erro de pariedade.
        case SerialPortEvent.CD:
        //Detecção de portadora.
        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
        //Limpa para enviar.
        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
        //Conjunto de dados prontos.
        case SerialPortEvent.RI:
        //Caminho indicado.
        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            /*Buffer de saída está vazio. O evento será gerado depois de uma gravação for concluída,
             quando o buffer do sistema torna-se vazia novamente..."
             */
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            /*Dados disponíveis na porta serial. "
             + "Este evento será gerada uma vez quando dados novos chegam na porta de série. "
             + "Mesmo se o usuário não ler os dados, "
             + "não será gerado novamente até a próxima vez que novos dados chegam");
             */
            try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500); // 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            int numBytes = 0;
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            }
            String result = new String(readBuffer);
            result = result.substring(0, numBytes);
            System.out.println(result + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        break;
    }
}
```